# Bluetooth android controller

Tags: android

Is it possible to make a bluetooth connection from an android to another non-android device (such as windows) then send functions to that device to control it? Such as windows START function? Like sending START cmd.exe or something of the sort. The basis is I want to control the device in a whole new way.

Comment: Why bluetooth and not HTTP or TCP requests over sockets?

Comment: Because not everyone has wifi. Also what happens if you are out of the house? Or routers down? Pretty useless application then. Besides I did not say I would not. But I would have a different method for that.

Comment: And not all PC's have bluetooth and bluetooth range isn't too great outside of a house. I guess I could see bluetooth in an scenario with no LAN connection

Comment: Okay just stop. Distance is not a problem. I am making a different function for HTTP that communicates to a server. But for now I need to start with the bluetooth for offline. I have fallbacks, other methods, but first is first to get the bluetooth running. Im just not familar with using it other than transfering files.

Comment: Bluetooth acts on Socket communication and transfers byte streams. Same concept of HTTP, which is where my comment originated. As the answer below states, you need a client and a server. One to build a message, then other to parse it back out in a sensible format. An example is [Android Bluetooth Chat](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat)

Comment: Both my devices have bluetooth and are constantly using it anyway. However i dont know how different itll be sending content.

Comment: The way I plan to do it, is to make a connection, send a string then have the classes on the main program take care of the rest... to keep it simple. So basically we have the desktop console app on windows taking care of that. The only thing the android app would do is send a number or two. Such as 1, 1 which would open CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'd need an app on both the phone and the PC.  The android app would send commands, and then you'd need to write a PC app that parses those commands and takes the appropriate action.  I'd be very careful about using such an app, as its obviously a complete security hole.

Comment: How can I do it without another app?

Comment: You can't.  Something on the pc has to listen to requests.

Comment: I see... Well minor setback but itll work. Is there a native ndk library to do such?

Comment: Would it be possible using either C++ or Java? Can they both connect via bluetooth.